# PostgreSQL search data in three tables with double left join

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get date from live table, it should be order by `live_ranking.live_reference_ranking` if `live_manage_op_log.expire_time > now()`, else, it should be order by `live.create_time2`.

The first SQL in the picture should contain the `vid` which returns the second SQL return, can you tell me where it is wrong?

The is the first SQL:

```
select live.vid from live left join 
    (select live_ranking.vid,
            live_ranking.reference_ranking from live_ranking,
            live_manage_op_log,live 
        where live.vid=live_ranking.vid and 
            live_ranking.vid=live_manage_op_log.vid and 
            live_manage_op_log.expire_time>1502850000) as lm 
        on live.vid=lm.vid 
            where public=1 and isaudit<5 and 
                vtype=1 and 
                need_pay=1
        order by lm.reference_ranking desc ,
            live.create_time2 desc 
        limit 10;
```

This results in :
[image: Result]

I am a non-native English speakers, if you don't understand me, I will try to explain my question.

Comment: frist sql:select live.vid from live  left join (select live_ranking.vid,live_ranking.reference_ranking from live_ranking,live_manage_op_log,live where live.vid=live_ranking.vid and live_ranking.vid=live_manage_op_log.vid and live_manage_op_log.expire_time>1502850000) as lm on live.vid=lm.vid where public=1 and isaudit<5 and vtype=1 and need_pay=1 order by lm.reference_ranking desc ,live.create_time2 desc limit 10;

Comment: second sql: select live.vid from live  join (select live_ranking.vid,live_ranking.reference_ranking from live_ranking,live_manage_op_log,live where live.vid=live_ranking.vid and live_ranking.vid=live_manage_op_log.vid and live_manage_op_log.expire_time>1502850000) as lm on live.vid=lm.vid where public=1 and isaudit<5 and vtype=1 and need_pay=1 order by lm.reference_ranking desc ,live.create_time2 desc limit 10;

Comment: Please don't post additions to the question in comments, nor should you post large blocks of code in comments. Please hit edit on your question and put the code in. Indent it with 4 spaces, or select it with the mouse and click the {} button above he text editor area to format it as code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to include the SQL as per the comments and to also embed the picture.

Comment: PostreSQL in the title, SQL Server in the tags. Which one is it then?

Comment: find another way to solve this,thanks for all your help!